# How Combinatorics started?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I recently was researching, on why ancient people feel the need of combinatorics. Few of them i found, it was used by Ancient Chinese for getting combinations of Hexagram, also used by Indians specifically Poet at that time to find combinations of tunes to get perfect tune. But by getting combinations, we are getting how many possible combinations are there, how is it useful inorder to find if particular combination is present or not? but getting total combination, i am just getting a big number, i mean what will i do with that? Thankyou for your reply inadvance!!

Comment: I believe this question is better suited for https://hsm.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Let me reformulate your question in a loose way  "what is the point to know how many items of that sort exist ; what we need is in fact the items themselves". 1) First answer : Yes but when you enumerate items, the risk is that you can forget one of them... knowing how many of the are helps you to look for the forgotten ones, or, on the other hand, indicate that you have too many of them (certain objects are duplicated). 2) Second answer : spotting isomorphic contexts ; the fact to find similar enumeration formulas might mean (not always) that one can "bridge" different theories

Comment: 3) The aestethics (as often in mathematics): the pleasure of counting.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks alot for your reply, it was really eye opening experience, may i request can you please more ellaborate on your second point :)

Comment: In fact, I have attempted a re-formulation of my answer under the form of an answer by taking (for the second point you are interested in) the example of the Catalan numbers.

Comment: Many counting problems arose from mystical/religious considerations: the arab mathematicians wanted to know how many "words" could be made with the arabic alphabet up to certain length as part of their investigations into the number of names of Allah; from there, some problems moved to mercantile considerations, and some of the same mathematicians who were counting permutations also asked questions about counting combinations, such as "in how many ways can I purchase 5 silks if there are 10 available colors?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me reformulate your question in a loose way to read: "what is the point to count how many items exist verifying a certain property; what we need is in fact the items themselves".

I see three types of counterarguments:

- 1. When you enumerate items verifying a certain property, you can forget some of them or count twice some others... knowing in a prior way how many we must find is a good blindstick.
- 2. Helping to discover isomorphism between seemingly non-connected issues : finding similar enumeration formulas probably means one can "bridge" the corresponding theories. A typical example are the ubiquitous Catalan numbers $C_n$. See [this document](https://math.ch/norbert.hungerbuehler/publications/catalan/catalan.pdf) where they give (at least) three ways to recognize them :

     a) By an explicit formula $C_n=\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}$

     b) by a recursive formula: $C_{n+1}=\sum_{k=0}^n C_k C_{n-k}$

     c) by their generating function $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}C_kx^k=\frac{1}{2x}(1-\sqrt{1-4x})$.

Recognizing any of these three formulas will allow you to say : my problem is likely to be isomorphic to another one in which the Catalan numbers are present. See in particular the examples they give in the above paper about counting the way one can parenthesize a word with $n$ letters and the number of binary rooted trees : if you are accustomed to trees, it will not take you long before recognizing that indeed these trees can be placed into a bijective correspondence with the parenthezised expressions. See as well the very nice Wikipedia article about [Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number).

Another more elaborated example is the so-called "pentagonal number theorem" of Euler with its rather unexpected proof by Franklin some 150 years later using the (also ubiquitous) Ferrer's diagrams : see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_number_theorem). See also [here](https://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath623/kmath623.htm)

3. The aesthetics (as often in Mathematics) : the OEIS site is full of examples of interesting connections. For example items counted by [Motzkin numbers](https://oeis.org/A001006).